# Parse: No list of apps from Parse in CTL windows 7

Tags: parse-platform

Steps to reproduce the issue in CTL windows.

1. parse new myapp (parse will create cloud, config and public folders)
2. give Email and password.
3. when you press enter you should see all the apps you have created as in your dashboard, but I am seeing "1: results"

Comment: releated bug has been opened at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/971635999542789/

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

I have posted a workaround that involves manually editing the `global.json` file:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30600790/383414

---

According to [Hector Ramos on this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/parse-developers/WoRnDft4qmE/rC6ssV0d8pgJ):

> If you run into this, please check what `parse cliversion` returns. If
>   it says 1.4.4 or earlier, then you're on an OLD VERSION and will need
>   to download the new CLI from https://parse.com/docs/downloads
>
> Make sure that the old binary is replaced by the new version, and that
>   `parse cliversion` returns a version number that is 2.0 or higher.

---

<strike>This did not help me, I have upgraded to v2.0.7 which behaved the same, and then to v2.0.8 which hangs my machine.</strike>

v2.1.3 fixes the issue for me.

---

For more info, check out that thread, and I will be updating information on my question:

- [parse.exe not seeing my projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578396/parse-exe-not-seeing-my-projects)